# Update app UI after split view controller display mode changes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I need to be able to update my app's UI when the split view controller's display mode changes. Specifically, if it goes from an expanded interface to a collapsed interface, I need to do something, and also if it goes from collapsed to expanded.

I am currently handling this via `traitCollectionDidChange` and while this seems to be working good for two of my split view controllers, the third one isn't working. It seems this method is getting called too early, so that when I check the `displayMode` to see if it's `UISplitViewcontrollerDisplayModeAllVisible`, the split view hasn't yet updated to the new display mode. So it ends up removing buttons that I want to actually want to add, or adds them when I wanted to remove them. If I delay checking that display mode just 0.1 second later, the `displayMode` value correctly represents what it will be when rotation completes and the appropriate action is taken.

My question is, is there a better method to use to update my app's UI, perhaps is there a way to know when the `displayMode` changes? I don't want to risk it calling it too early, but I also don't want to wait until rotation completes to update the UI. Delaying the check is a very fragile solution that may easily result in unexpected behavior, sometimes it might not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more robust solution would be to use `primaryViewControllerForCollapsingSplitViewController:` and `primaryViewControllerForExpandingSplitViewController:` in the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`.

From the documentation it says

> If you do not implement this method, or if your implementation
>   returns nil, the split view controller chooses its primary view
>   controller as the one to display.

So implement these methods to track collapse and expand, then return `nil` and you'll still get the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

had a similar issue and discovered this delegate method on [UISplitViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:)

```
func targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController) -> UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode
```

Only problem is that it when you ask svc.displayMode, it tells you what mode its coming from and not where its going.  However, its enough info to be able to prevent the UISplitViewController from going into a particular state.

```
    func targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController) -> UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode {
    switch svc.displayMode {
    case    .PrimaryOverlay :
        return .AllVisible
    case .AllVisible :
        return .PrimaryHidden
    case .PrimaryHidden :
        return .AllVisible
    case .Automatic :
        return .AllVisible
    default:
        return .AllVisible
    }
}
```

The other delegate method that I was able to use to know when my UISplitViewController display mode was changing is

```
func splitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController, willChangeToDisplayMode displayMode: UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)
```

Then you can change the view accordingly if you handle the states that matter to you

```
 func splitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController, willChangeToDisplayMode displayMode: UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode) {
    println("will change to display mode \(displayMode.rawValue)")


    if (displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible) {
           //do something because EVERYTHING is visible      
    } else if (displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryHidden) {
       //something else because the primary is GONE
    } else if (self.splitViewController?.displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryOverlay){
       //handle primary overlay change
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears if the `UISplitViewController:preferredDisplayMode` is `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic`, its delegate's `targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:` method allows you to retrieve the `displayMode` from the `UISplitViewController` **AFTER** an action that changes it - like the `displayModeButtonItem`, a swipe gesture, rotation, etc.  That retrieved `displayMode` will NOT be `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic` - it will reflect the actual primary/secondary display status.

As [bolnad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664368/bolnad) inferred, the `targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:` delegate method is for you to specify the `displayMode` to use at the NEXT action ("where it's going") in the `UISplitViewController`, which is not required to be soon.

In my use, since my `UISplitViewController.preferredDisplayMode` is always `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic`, I trigger whatever activities I need after a `displayMode` change, then return `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic` for the future.

Answer (score 0):

> If I delay checking that display mode just 0.1 second later, the displayMode value correctly represents what it will be when rotation completes and the appropriate action is taken.

All you want to do is update UI after the display mode changed.And it works when you set a 0.1s delay.

So,the solution is very easy,you just need to put your code at the end of `main thread runloop`,using GCD

```
// Swift3.0
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // your code here
}
```

It means your code will be executed after `UI/Main Thread` is completed its previous works such as layoutSubviews,rotation or change displayMode.Your approach that set a 0.1s delay may not work correctly if your `Main/UI Thread` is too busy to handle the previous work in 0.1s

If you don't understand clearly,you should refer to documents about `RunLoop` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html)

Comment: FWIW This is a risky approach that might fail if Apple changes the APIs. It's better to use the delegate functions Apple provides, especially `splitViewController(:willChangeToDisplayMode:)`